# How do you see inside a mysqli_query object to trouble shoot?

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, mysqli

I've come into this problem a few times and it's a pain. Right now the line `if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 1)` gives the error `mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given` and $result is the result of `mysqli_query()`. I can't echo `$result` and I tried the following code to find out what's inside $result with no success

```
if (!mysqli_query($link, "SET @a:='this will not work'"))
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
```

I'm trying to trouble shoot but it's like I come to a dead end because I can't see inside the result of `mysqli_query()`.

How can I find the source of the problem? I'm guessing it's bad SQL syntax but I need more details.

Here is the PHP code where `$result` is defined

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `password`
                        FROM `ajax_login`
                        WHERE userid = \''.$userName.'\' LIMIT 1');
```

Comment: can you post the relevant code as well, not just bits and unconnected pieces?

Comment: post the whole php code please. we need to see where you set $result as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you checking the error code/message? Something like:

```
if(mysqli_errno($link)){
    die(mysqli_error($link));
}
```

(of course, you wouldn't use `die` in production)

Comment: That led me to the problem. I had forgotten the table name had changed.